# Ubuntu on android linux deploy -sudo perm_root permission denied

Tags: sudo, android

I have installed ubuntu on samsung galaxy s3 using linux deploy and 
I can get the desktop using VNC.

But I cant seem to use `sudo`? For example if I say:
`sudo apt-get install git`
I get :

`sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0,-1,-1): permission denied`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this. In linux deploy settings change the user to root.

This then logs you in as root and you dont need to use sudo.